# I need to send 2. parameter to function with my tupple list on haskell language

Tags: haskell

I am very new to the this language. Im trying to write a function take 2 argument one is tuple list (Int,Int) second is min value . The function look every tuple in list and sum the tuple values (a,b) if a+b> min value write this tuple to the console.

I wrote this code

```
 calc::[(Int,Int)]->[(Int,Int)]

 calc  xs  = if xs==[]
                then []
             else if (fst (head xs) + snd(head xs))>5
                then head xs:calc(tail xs )
             else calc(tail xs )
```

And I can't send minvalue parameter to function.

I have to change that 5 value to min value help please

Comment: It is recommended to use pattern matching as much as possible. Functions like `head, tail` are dangerous and should be avoided if possible. `fst,snd` are safe, but often unnecessary when you use pattern matching properly. E.g. `calc [] = [] ; calc ((a,b):xs) = if a+b>5 then (a,b):calc xs else calc xs` exploits pattern matching and avoids every function. Then, well, this can be shortened as shown in the answer below using `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the parameter type and name, and to the recursive calls, like this:

```
 calc::Int->[(Int,Int)]->[(Int,Int)]

 calc minvalue xs  = if xs==[]
                then []
             else if (fst (head xs) + snd(head xs))>minvalue
                then head xs:calc minvalue(tail xs )
             else calc minvalue(tail xs )
```

However, your function is a big unidiomatic mess. You could just write this instead:

```
calc minvalue = filter (\(x,y) -> x + y > minvalue)
```